# How to hide a search bar when scrolling down and how to show it when scrolling up with react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have a Search Bar, I only need the functionality that when it scrolls down it disappears and when it scrolls up it appears but I do not know how, if someone can show me a concrete example of how to do that functionality, I would be deluxe until then I show my code :)

```
showSearchBarIOS = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerSearchBarIOS}>
        <Icon name="search" size={20} style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputIos}
          value={this.state.text}
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType="done"
          onChangeText={this.submitText}
          placeholder="Buscar..."
          placeholderTextColor={GRIS_DEFAULT}
        />
        <Text>{this.props.texto}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  showSearchBarAndroid = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerSearchBarAndroid}>
        <Icon
          name="search"
          size={25}
          style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginBottom: 3 }}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputAndroid}
          value={this.state.text}
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType="done"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text: text })}
          placeholder="Buscar Diputados..."
          placeholderTextColor={GRIS_DEFAULT}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

showList = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {Platform.OS === "ios"
          ? this.showSearchBarIOS()
          : this.showSearchBarAndroid()}
        <RecyclerListView
          layoutProvider={this._layoutProvider}
          dataProvider={this.props.dataProvider}
          rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
          scrollViewProps={{
            refreshControl: (
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.props.diputadosNomina.isFetching}
                onRefresh={this.props.fetchDiputadosNomina}
                colors={[REFRESH_CONTROL_COLOR]}
                tintColor={REFRESH_CONTROL_COLOR}
              />
            )
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: PAGE_BACKGROUND_COLOR
  },
  containerSearchBarIOS: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 30,
    padding: 0,
    marginLeft: 6,
    marginRight: 6,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: BACKGROUND_SEARCH_BAR,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: GRIS_DEFAULT,
    borderRadius: 60
  },
  containerSearchBarAndroid: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 40,
    padding: 0,
    marginLeft: 2,
    marginRight: 2,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: BACKGROUND_SEARCH_BAR,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: GRIS_DEFAULT,
    borderRadius: 60
  },
  textInputIos: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: Roboto_Regular,
    width: "90%",
    padding: 2
  },
```

textInputAndroid: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: Roboto_Regular,
    width: "90%"
  }

Comment: Can you share your actual code? I do not believe what you shared will run.

You will need to absolutely position your search bar within the container view and animate it with the `onScroll` event of the list view you are using.

Comment: for security reasons I can not share my code but if you show me an example of how to do the displacement I am looking for I would appreciate it

Comment: so you understand a little better I'm looking to do this in react-native.
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-gould-lh4rw

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-tree-x3jxz). Basically this is it:

```
    const HideOnScroll = () => {
    const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState(window.scrollY);
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const onScroll = () => {
            setVisible(window.scrollY > scroll)
            setScroll(window.scrollY)
        }
        window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    });

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "200vh" }}>
            {visible && (
                <div style={{ position: "fixed" }}>Only show scrolling down</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: great looking for something like that only when it returns to down disappear

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't undestood. Could you explain it better?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing you did but implemented in react-native since you implemented it in react js and it's not the same

Comment: The gist here is the logic. In RN you don't even have to remove the listener. Just listen to the `onScroll` event on a `View` component instead of a div. And access the `window.scrollY` at `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following medium blog that will help you to create the view like search bar hide/show on scroll up/down:

https://blog.expo.io/implementation-complex-animation-in-react-native-by-example-search-bar-with-tab-view-and-collapsing-68bb43be2dcb

Answer (score -1):

Something similar to this maybe?

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.prev = window.scrollY;
    this.show = false;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleNavigation(e);
}

handleNavigation = (e) =>{
    const window = e.currentTarget;

    if(this.prev > window.scrollY){
        this.show = true;
    }
    else if(this.prev < window.scrollY){
        this.show = false;
    }
    this.prev = window.scrollY;
};

render () {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      { this.show && <SearchBar /> }
    <Fragment/>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is extremely basic.  What wasn't clear to you?